# EOFError: Ran out of input While Loading

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to create a text-based game that requires a save and load function. I have created the function but get this error when I am trying to load.

import pickle
import os
import os.path
from os import system, name
#Character class
class character:

```
def __init__(self, fname, lname, trust, anger):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.trust = trust
    self.anger = anger

Silez = character("Silez", "", 0, 0)

Xenon = character("Xenon", "", 0, 0)

Neko = character("Neko", "", 0, 0)

Aroma = character("Aroma", "", 0, 0)

Castellano = character("Castellano", "", 0, 0)

One = character("One", "", 0, 0)

Six = character("Six", "", 0, 0)

Rin = character("Rin", "", 0, 0)
#- End of: Character initialisation -

#Game variables
mode = ""
current_chapter = 0
prev_chapter = current_chapter - 1
load_and_save = [Silez, Xenon, Neko, Aroma, Castellano, One, Six, Rin, current_chapter]

def save():
  global load_and_save
  with open('sav.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(load_and_save, f, protocol=2)

def load():
  global load_and_save
  with open('sav.dat', 'rb') as f:
    for elem in load_and_save:
      load_and_save = pickle.load(f)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 170, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 163, in main
    load()
  File "main.py", line 85, in load
    load_and_save = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: You're doing just one dump call, but several load calls. That can't possibly be right: Each dump should correspond to exactly one load.

Comment: So what would the right way to do this, be?

Comment: Take out the `for elem in load_and_save:` loop from the `load()` function so that you only call `pickle.load()` _once_.